# Mongoose Finding data in Sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this model

```
//user notif schema

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserNotifSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    NotifType       : {type : Number}, 
    NotifData       : {
        User_source_id  : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User'}, // for course, forking
        Course_id       : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Course'}, // for course
        UserFile_id     : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'UserFile'} // for forking
    },
    NotifTarget : [
        {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User'}
    ],
    Created_at      : {type : Date, required : true, default : Date.now},
});


var UserNotif = mongoose.model('UserNotif', UserNotifSchema);
module.exports = UserNotif;
```

I create a model that contains user notification by `NotifTarget`. I want to get some notif to specific user and doing like this

```
var user_id = req.session.userLogin.UserId;

    NotifModel.find({'NotifTarget' : user_id})
                .populate('NotifTarget')
                .exec(function(err, doc){
                    if (err){
                        res.send(err);
                    }
                    else{
                        res.send(doc);
                    }
                })
```

This is ok when there only one array `user_id` in `NotifTarget` but return empty array when I give multiple data in `NotifTarget`. Are there any solution for this?

Comment: How are you giving multiple data in `NotifTarget`?

Comment: If the user_id is an array of ids you should use `{ NotifTarget: { $in: user_id} }`. I also think you should convert each element of user_id array to `objectId` if you have them as strings.

Comment: Thank HosseinAgha, this is work

Comment: Talha Awan, I just create notif for group of people.. Like group assigment in a course. So I make like that